# How to count number of sentences occurring in the built-in sentences vector ending with the words as “day”, “pay”, or “way”?

Tags: r, text-mining

I read a text into R using the `readChar()` function. I recently discovered the `stringr` package, which helped me a great deal to do useful things with my text such as counting the number of characters and the total number of occurrences of each letter in the entire text. Now, I need to count the number of sentences in the built-in sentences vector ending with the
words “day”, “pay”, or “way”, it should not count the sentences if the last word is not exactly one of them (e.g. away). Does R have any function, which can help me do that?

Comment: Regular expressions will be your friend I imagine, e.g.: `grepl("\\b[wpd]ay$", c("this is the way", "you pay", "one day", "up and away"))` - `str_detect` should have the same functionality in the *stringr* package - `str_detect(c("this is the way", "you pay", "one day", "up and away"), "\\b[wpd]ay$")`

Comment: I'm not getting it, can you please clarify with code in R language?

Comment: What @thelatemail said. But you’ll want to add a period at the end for the sentences in `sentences` — so your regex would be `"\\b[wpd]ay\\.$"`.

Comment: @eas - both lines are valid code in R. I'm searching for strings ending in `w` `p` or `d` + `ay` followed by the end of the string `$` using regular expressions.

Comment: @eas regular expressions are the tool used for these kinds of tasks across many languages, including in R. Have a look at the [section on regular expressions](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html#matching-patterns-with-regular-expressions) in *R for Data Science.*

Comment: @thelatemail nice use of `[wpd]`.

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail I got the concept and working of str_detect()

Comment: If you need to count the number of sentences where the pattern occurs, `sum(grepl(.))` will add the `FALSE/TRUE`, or `0/1` values.